# media file not found in a simple django-admin application

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have seen many questions here regarding media files in Django, but honestly I can't find a valid solution for my problem.
So I have decided to streamline the environment to a very simple application.
You can find it here: [github project](https://github.com/mg64ve/django-docs)
I have created a project with django-admin and I called 'documents' and then I have created an app called 'docs'.
Then I defined a simple class:

```
    def get_path(instance, filename):
   fn, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
   ts = str(int(time.time()))
   return os.path.join('{}_{}{}'.format(fn, ts, ext))

class doc(models.Model):
    doc_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name=u"doc name", help_text=u"name of the doc")
    doc_document = models.FileField(upload_to=get_path, verbose_name=u"document", help_text=u"document")

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("doc_name", )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.doc_name}"
```

This changes the filename and it adds a timestamp.
I also changed the urls.py file adding the following:

```
path(r'', admin.site.urls),
```

Now the question is: without using MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT is it possible to make this working?
I have tried to add a files and it works:

[image: file_added]

and it properly save the file in the root of the project.
But when I go to the link and click I am getting the following:

[image: click_file]

Now is it possible to know where is it looking for the file?
Do you think that adding MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT would help? How should I add it?
I have already tried but without any success.

**Additional information**

If I set my project in urls.py:

[image: urls.py]

Then I am getting this:

[image: page_not_found]

Comment: where the file get storedis it in you static folder because if you ca add some file it will be stored somewhere

Comment: I know where the file is stored. I can't access that file from Django application and I can't understand why?

Comment: add you main project urls.py

Comment: @Shreyash, please check my notes under "Additional information". It does not solve the problem and I am still getting page not found error.

Answer (score 0):

Following the tutorial: https://www.sitepoint.com/django-photo-sharing-app/
I basically changed 3 things:

1-created docs/urls.py and put:

```
urlpatterns = []
```

2-changed documents/urls.py to:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # Main app
    path('', include('docs.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

3-in documents/settings.py just put the following:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'
```

it works.